# How to slice an object into a variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new in Javascript. I have an object and I need to compare it with a variable and then if conditions are met I do something. How can i get access to the fields that I need?

[image]

I took this variable: `$scope.acceptedProjects['hash'][key]['title']`

[image]

Here is my code:

```
$scope.overlappingDates = overlappingDates;
$scope.acceptedProjects = invitationService.acceptedProjects;

for(var value in $scope.overlappingDates) {
    for(var key in $scope.acceptedProjects['hash']) {
        console.log($scope.overlappingDates);
        console.log($scope.acceptedProjects['hash'][key]['title']);
    }
}
return;
```

If I try `$scope.overlappingDates[value]`, it returns 
[image]
And I just need to slice or do something to convert this massive name to var.

Comment: It's not clear what data structure you operate on, and what is the expected result. To execute actions on array items which meet some condition you may use the combination of `for` loop with `if` statement, or array methods `filter` to filter neccesary items and `forEach` to loop through items and do anything with their data.

Comment: Is question about getting overlap1 value or about getting fields of elements in overlap1 array?

Comment: @Michael Kapustey, question is about give any variable value overlap1.

Comment: @ЕвгенийСавичев final result should be example_var = overlap1. What syntax should i use to get value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I've got what do you want to achieve. But look at this abstract example step by step and understand what is going on here. I hope this will help you to get more familiar with accessing object properties and array items:

```
var data = {
    prop1: [
        {meaning_property: 1},
        {meaning_property: 2},
        {meaning_property: 3}
    ],
    prop2: [
        {meaning_property: 4},
        {meaning_property: 5},
        {meaning_property: 6}
    ]
};

var found_field_name = null;
var found_item_index = -1;

var looking_for_value = 5;

// loop through data's fields
for (var prop in data) {
    // access the value of object's field prop1, prop2 etc...
    var arr = data[prop];
    // loop through array
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var item = arr[i];
        // item property value meets the condition?
        if (item.meaning_property === looking_for_value) {
            // remember field name for array
            found_field_name = prop;
            // remember item index in array
            found_item_index = i;
            // break the cycle here, we've found what we need
            break;
        }

        /**
         * item.meaning_property you can also access in different ways
         * arr[i].meaning_property
         * data[prop][i].meaning_property
         * data["prop1"][0].meaning_property
         * data.prop1[0].meaning_property
         */
    }
}

// if we found something during previos loop
if (found_field_name !== null) {
    // access the corresponding array
    var arr = data[found_field_name];
    // access the corresponding item
    var item = arr[found_item_index];
    console.log("Item found", found_field_name, found_item_index, arr, item);
}
else {
    console.log("No items met the criteria");
}
```

Try to play with this code, I'm sure, you'll find the way to solve your task finally.

Answer (score 0):

From the browser output I see, that overlap1 is array that contains objects inside. Thats how to get object values

```
for (var i = 0; i < overlap1.length; i++;){ //iterate over all objects inside array
    var el = overlap1[i];
    //get variables of object
    var projectDateId = el.project_date_id// or el["project_date_id"];
    var projectsProjectId = el.projects_project_id// or el["projects_project_id"];
    //do something with this variables
}
```